# getchar() function getting enter as input

Tags: c, getchar

Here, I'm trying to get the user's input with getchar(); so the loop runs fine for the first time, but on the second time it's not getting input and moving to the 3rd iteration automatically. I think a newline is doing something here. How can this be resolved?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
char input = ' ';
int v, c;
v=c=0;

while(input != '!'){
  puts("Enter a char");
  input = getchar();

  switch(input){
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
    case 'E':
    case 'e':
    case 'I':
    case 'i':
    case 'O':
    case 'o':
    case 'U':
    case 'u':
      v=v+1;
      break;
    default:
      c = c+1;
  }
}

if(v>c)
 puts("Vowel wins.");
else if(c>v)
 puts("Constant wins.");
else
 puts("It's a  tie.");
}
```

Here is the online code in the compiler, you can run yourself directly for ease. 
https://onlinegdb.com/HyEzo7w-I

Comment: It's probably because of the carriage return left in the input stream after you read the first character. You need to clear your input stream before using getchar again.

Comment: `while(getchar() != '\n') continue;`

Comment: `getchar` gets each character in the input stream, including newlne characgters. Add a case for newline characters. Or, more generally, add an `if` statement to prevent entering the `switch` statement when the input character is not a letter.

Comment: `getchar()` wants an `int`, `char input = ' ';` --> `int input = ' ';`

Comment: getchar() wants an int, char input = ' '; --> int input = ' ';  tried it, that's not working, still getting the same result.

Comment: I guess you mean **consonants**, not **constants**, but the calculation is wrong - ofc, since you increment it for each *character* which in C includes `!`, spaces and newlines alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting a character in the command line you are really inserting two characters, it's the character itself and and the newline character(`\n`), so the first `getchar()` gets the character and the second `getchar()` gets the newline character, so it jumps to the third `getchar()`.

If you press only enter you can see that it cycles only once since enter is only one newline charater, you can solve this by putting two getchar(), so the second catches the `\n`:

```
while(input != '!'){
  puts("Enter a char");
  input = getchar();
  getchar();
///...
```

Or create a case in you switch for the newline character.

```
case '\n': break;
```

Comment: Thank you for the proper guidance.